# "Block not encountered" indicator wrong...?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, post-ban

In a site where I'm a moderator, we have a user complaining that they cannot post a question, as the website throws him an error message. I went to check the user's profile page and saw that he *was* question-blocked, but it "had not yet been encountered."

"Block not encountered"? Sure sounds like it should have been! Am I missing something?

Comment: Let me know if I should post a link to the user/question. Its not hard to find, but I'm erring on the side of too little information here.

Comment: Maybe he put "question" or something in the title, so it was rejected before the block even got to see it?

Comment: @DanBron - Just tried posting a question with the title "I have a question", the system didn't complain for me. Also, we have [at least one other question with the word "question" in the title](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54821/applying-for-phd-programs-in-florida-i-have-a-question-about-legal-questions).

Comment: @eykanal A lot of restrictions are disabled for high-rep users and moderators; unless you tried that from a new account it doesn't really represent.

Comment: I know on Stack Overflow there is an automated quality filter (don't know if it's rep dependent) that takes things like grammar, length of question, etc. into account to tell if the question is up to a certain standard of quality. I've always assumed this was on all sites. Provided it is, it sounds like the user hit _that_ block, rather than the actual question ban block. As far as I am aware, the actual question ban message doesn't mention that the question doesn't "respect quality standards", but rather says no more questions may be posted from that account.

Answer (score 10):

The user was *not* blocked at the time they were complaining about whatever error they were getting. Since then, they've gotten downvotes which triggered a block which hasn't yet been hit.

Also to clarify: when a user hits the block, they cannot type *anything* into the Ask page. It simply gives them an error message.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. If there was a sandbox available to mods that simulates the experience of users with varying degrees of block (or even just an unlisted youtube video demoing the site that way), I would appreciate it. People complain of weird stuff and I rarely know what they're experiencing.

Comment: You're a mod, you have pretty broad control over this stuff on your own site, @eykanal... So create a sock puppet, block it, and then record a video.